# How do I wait for lulls in channel activity to trigger something?

Tags: go, debouncing

I have a channel that will receive bursts of writes to it. I want to wait until a burst of sends on the channel have finished before triggering an action.

I have looked at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/leolara/d62b87797b0ef5e418cd), however, it will send on the output every `interval`if there is data in the buffer:

```
func debounceChannel(interval time.Duration, output chan int) chan int {
  input := make(chan int)

  go func() {
    var buffer int
    var ok bool

    // We do not start waiting for interval until called at least once
    buffer, ok = <-input 
    // If channel closed exit, we could also close output
    if !ok {
      return
    }

    // We start waiting for an interval
    for {
      select {
      case buffer, ok = <-input:
        // If channel closed exit, we could also close output
        if !ok {
          return
        }

      case <-time.After(interval):
        // Interval has passed and we have data, so send it
        output <- buffer
        // Wait for data again before starting waiting for an interval
        buffer, ok = <-input
        if !ok {
          return
        }
        // If channel is not closed we have more data and start waiting for interval
      }
    }
  }()

  return input
}
```

In my case, I want to wait until there is no longer any data being sent on the input channel for this burst before triggering or sending on the output.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean put all data to input channel then read these one by one to output channel?

Comment: No. I have an input channel that receives data in bursts. I want to read from the input and only write to the output channel once every time a burst of data has been read.

Comment: Can you expand on the comment "wait until all the writes have finished"? Is the intention to use a delay as a signal?

Comment: @Mark, I updated my question and changed it to "a burst of sends on the channel". I have found a solution to my problem and have posted some code implementing that as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up implementing as my debouncer:

```
func Debounce(lull time.Duration, in chan struct{}, out chan struct{}) {

    go func() {

        var last int64 = 0

        for {
            select {
            case <-in:
                last = time.Now().Unix()

            case <-time.Tick(lull):
                if last != 0 && time.Now().Unix() >= last+int64(lull.Seconds()) {
                    last = 0
                    out <- struct{}{}
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

It takes a lull time which is the duration where if we do not receive on the input, then we assume there is a break in the bursts of data. There are 2 channels, 1 input and 1 output. The bursts of data arrives on the input, and for each burst, we write to the output channel at the end of the burst.

The implementation is extremely simplistic. I just store the current unix timestamp every time I receive from the input channel. Then, I have a ticker ticking with a duration of the lull time. All this does is check to see if we've exceeded the wait time for the last burst. If so, it resets `last` to 0 an emits an event on the output channel.

Here's some code using the debounce function with a lull time of 2 seconds which sends random bursts on the input channel:

```
func main() {

    out := make(chan struct{})
    in := make(chan struct{})

    Debounce(2*time.Second, in, out)

    // Generating bursts of input data
    go func(in chan struct{}) {

        for {
            select {
            case <-time.Tick(1 * time.Second):
                in <- struct{}{}

                fmt.Println("Sending!")

                shouldSleep := rand.Intn(2)
                if shouldSleep == 1 {
                    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                }
            }
        }
    }(in)

    // Listening for output events
    go func(out chan struct{}) {

        for _ = range out {
            fmt.Println("Got an event!")
        }
    }(out)

    // Do not let main terminate.
    done := make(chan struct{})
    <-done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need synchronization between goroutines, perhaps along this line.

```
func main() {

        // Create a channel for our input
        input := make(chan int, 1)
        // Create another for synchronization between main and forked goroutines
        done := make(chan bool)

        go func() {
                // block-wait for received value
                <-input

                // do some more things here

                // when done, send signal to the main goroutine
                done <- true
        }()

        // Do something while wait for the forked goroutine

        // this block until `<-done`
        <-done
        close(mychan)
}
```

This [post](https://medium.com/code-zen/concurrency-in-go-5fcba11acb0f#.s7wbsadzl) explains quite clear about synchronization using channels and sync group.

Answer (score 0):

What I've used as a debouncer:

```
package pkg

import (
    "context"
    "time"
)

// Debounce takes a channel, and will notify the output channel with the last received message after a lull duration.
// Upon cancel, it will check one last time for a message.
// Cancelling the ctx will cause the goroutine to exit.
func Debounce[T any](ctx context.Context, lull time.Duration, input <-chan T, output chan<- T) {

    
    go func() {
        var (
            buffer   *T
            minTimer = time.NewTimer(min)
            flush    = func() {
                if buffer != nil {
                    // don't block if we couldn't send
                    select {
                    case output <- *buffer:
                    default:
                    }
                    buffer = nil
                }
            }
        )
        defer minTimer.Stop()

        hits := 0
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // try and get last message
                select {
                case tmpBuf, ok := <-input:
                    if !ok {
                        break
                    }
                    buffer = &tmpBuf
                default:
                }
                flush()
                return
            case tmpBuf, ok := <-input:
                if !ok {
                    flush()
                    return
                }
                hits++
                buffer = &tmpBuf
            case <-minTimer.C:
                flush()
                minTimer.Reset(min)
            }
        }
    }()
}
```